# Angular 9.0.5 can't bind ngIf and ngFor

Tags: angular

I already have imported the CommonModule and BrowserModule, in one of my components it's works fine, but when i'm trying to do an *ngIf in other components view it's not working and Google console display me this warning core.js:8046 Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (cause in the div i'm using the *ngIf). I assume that's it's the angular version but i have no solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `BrowserModule` should be imported in the app module, in other modules, `CommonModule` should be imported instead.

So in your app module :

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'

...
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  ...
})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i already have all imported, but i have an "admin-layout module" where i imported my components and i forgot to add the component here, it's solved.